# Prevent downloading app to iPod

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, ipod

I'm developing an `app` which I want that can be `download-able` by just `iPhone` not via `iPod` Touches like **Whatsapp**.

On **Whatsapp** example, you can see **Whatsapp** in the market but when you push to download it blocks you so you can't download it.

I have find a way to determine device and `shutdown app` but it still in iPod device.

What are you suggestions ?

Thanks in advance.